# .htaccess: SetEnvIf Host doesn't work for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I have to set different Env for different subdomains. For example, domain/subdomain1 MAGE_RUN_CODE=mobile_en, but domain/subdomain2 MAGE_RUN_CODE=global

This code works:

```
SetEnvIf Host .*mydomain.net.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=mobile_en
```

But this code doesn't work

```
SetEnvIf Host .*mydomain.net/ahava-m1-mobile.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=mobile_en
```

How should I change second code to make it working?

Comment: SetEnvIf's host  keyword is for testing host header only. You can not test uri using this keyword. use mod-rewrite instead.

Comment: or check the SetEnvIf manual on apache site.

Comment: the `Host` does not contain a path part, ie anything after `.net`

Comment: "...for different subdomains" - your examples imply a "subdirectory", not a "subdomain"?!

Comment: @user82217 fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments above, **HOST** keyword is used for http host headers ie **example.com** . Since your url contains a path segment **/ahava-m1-mobile** you need to match against Request-uri variable.

```
SetEnvIF request_uri ^/ahava-m1-mobile MAGE_RUN_CODE=mobile_en
```